# Earth Engine: downloaded image contains only 1 pixel after mosaic with python version

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I followed the tutorial of getting a free-cloud landsat8 image from the official site with python version. But I got only 1 pixel with the function getDownloadUrl.Here's the code

```
def maskClouds(image):
    scored = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image)
    return image.updateMask(scored.select(['cloud']).lt(20))

def addQualityBands(image):
    return maskClouds(image).addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start'))

landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1').filterDate(2017-08-01, 2018-08-01)
landsat = landsat.map(addQualityBands).qualityMosaic('system:time_start')
landsat1 = landsat.select('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7')
url = landsat1.getDownloadUrl({
    'region': [[-120, 35], [-119, 35], [-119, 34], [-120, 34]]
})
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the tutorial?

Comment: [tutorria]https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_composite_mosaic

Answer (score 2):

Your use of [ee.ImageCollection.qualityMosaic()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionqualitymosaic) creates an ee.Image object with a default projection ([EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)) with a unit size of 1 degree. Because you are requesting a 1x1 degree region, that results in a single pixel.

To change this, specify projection information (some combination of the parameters `crs`, `crs_transform`, `scale`, `dimensions`) in your call to [ee.Image.getDownloadURL()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagegetdownloadurl). For example:

```js
url = landsat1.getDownloadUrl({
    'region': [[-120, 35], [-119, 35], [-119, 34], [-120, 34]],
    'scale': 1000
})
```

Here is a full working example:
https://gist.github.com/tylere/5c669252743c978aa993fe3f36479e66

Comment: thanks for  your response! Though I have solved this problem, I still learned much from details in your answers.